# Simple IF.. Else.. mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
set @var=1;
if @var>1 then 
select * from client;
else
select * from otherTable;
end if;
```

This is my mysql query. Can you guys point out why is it showing error?
This is really eating my brains out.

The Error displayed is

```
IF @var >1 THEN SELECT *
FROM client;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @var>1 then
select * from client' at line 1
```

Fast answer would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you have to execute that in a trigger or procedure.

You can't just run script code without a function around it.

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc ()
BEGIN
   set @var=1;
   if @var>1 then 
      select * from client;
   else
      select * from otherTable;
   end if;
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

After that you can execute it with

```
call simpleproc()
```

Comment: huh! just to run that query it will need a procedure? Hmm.. I am really new to mysql. Thanks will try that out

Comment: Can you please give an example creating a procedure around it?

Comment: Thanks very much.. But what does the "Delimeter" do?

Comment: the default delimiter is `;`. But if you want to create the procedure the DB engine would think your statement ends at the first `;`. That would lead to an incomplete statement. You can define another delimiter and then use it to mark the end of procedure. `delimiter ;` sets the delimiter back to `;` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If both tables have the same columns, you could use a UNION query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Client WHERE @var>1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM otherTable WHERE @var<=1
```

Please see an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1734/2).