# MySQL: If select in table X is empty, do select in table Y

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

in one query I would like to select information from table X.
however if table X doesn't return any information I would like to retrieve data from table Y.

Apart from each other the queries would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableY WHERE user_id=1

SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id=1
```

I tried the following to combine this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT * FROM tableY WHERE user_id= 
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id=1), 1, 0)
```

and of course the other way around

```
SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id= 
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableY WHERE user_id=1), 1, 0)
```

Bot versions will only execute the first query, but not the second.
So I am kinda stuck here.

I also tried this, but as the tables do not have the same rows this shouldn't work... and thats correct it doesn't work:

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM orbib.billing_address 
      WHERE user_id=1
  UNION ALL
      SELECT * 
      FROM orbib.users 
      WHERE id=1
          AND NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * 
              FROM orbib.billing_address 
              WHERE user_id=1
              )
```

Also tried doing this with a [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716425/simple-if-else-mysql-query) as explained here:

However this didn't help as well, besides that it looks like the procedure is saved, causing the user id to always be 1, and this of course varies.

Maybe anybody has an idea how to create a query which does do what I want?

EDITS:
  Here are table descriptions:

tableX:

```
Field       Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra
id          int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
username    varchar(30)     NO      UNI     NULL        
firstname   varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
lastname    varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
street      varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
street_nr   varchar(10)     YES             NULL        
zipcode     varchar(10)     YES             NULL        
city        varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
password    varchar(255)    NO              NULL        
salt        varchar(255)    NO      UNI     NULL        
email       varchar(255)    NO              NULL        
create_time datetime        NO              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
company     varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
branche     varchar(45)     YES             NULL
```

tableY:

```
Field           Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra
id              int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
user_id         int(11)         NO              NULL        
company         varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
contact_name    varchar(100)    YES             NULL        
street          varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
street_nr       varchar(10)     YES             NULL        
zipcode         varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
city            varchar(45)     YES             NULL        
terms_ok        tinyint(1)      YES             NULL        
billing_ok      tinyint(1)      YES             NULL
```

So from the idea from @kickstart I tried to do this:

```
SELECT 
     IFNULL(tableY.company, tableX.company) company,
     IFNULL(tableY.contact_name, tableX.lastname) contact,
     IFNULL(tableY.street, tableX.street) street,
     IFNULL(tableY.street_nr, tableX.street_nr) street_nr,
     IFNULL(tableY.zipcode, tableX.zipcode) zipcode,
     IFNULL(tableY.city, tableX.city) city
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableX) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableY ON tableY.user_id=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableX ON tableX.id=1
```

This gave me the error: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias.
But found the solution I forgot the x in the FROM (SELECT)

After changing this it worked, resulting on two rows however, so I need to change this a bit.

Tnx @kickstarter

Comment: Can you show some sample data for an example where you want data that doesn't exist in one table, but does in the other? This would help others recreate the issue and understand the question a lot better.

Comment: Is this intended to bring back a single row, or does each table contain multiple rows for the value?

Comment: Tnx both for a response. 
@McAdam331 See my edits for the tables

Comment: @Kickstart At this point tableX can only have one row and tableY multiple, though I want to change this so it can only contain one row with one user_id so which ever works best ;)

Comment: Do the tables have *any* relation between them? eg. TableX.id and TableY.user_id?

Comment: yes they do have relations

Comment: Well, what is the relation (and which columns are involved) between the two tables? An OUTER JOIN (LEFT/RIGHT/FULL) can be used to find "missing rows" after relations have been established. Derived queries can be used to easily rename columns once the common subset is established.

Comment: For the error (although *please do not use SO as 'live debugging'*): `FROM (SELECT * FROM tableX)` - all derived tables must use an alias. e.g `FROM (SELECT * FROM tableX) tabX`, but it's silly to have that useless `(SELECT * FROM ..)` anyway and it should be trivially eliminated ..

Comment: The sub query is not trivial for that solution, but it should be a sub query to return a single row (what the row is doesn't matter, it is purely there to attach the rows from the other 2 tables to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a major assumption that this is to return a single row, then possibly have a sub query to generate a single row and then LEFT OUTER JOIN the other 2 tables to that row.

Then you can use a load of IF statements to decide which tables values to return.

Efficiency is not likely to be its strong point!

```
SELECT IF(tableY.user_id IS NULL, tableX.id, tableY.user_id) AS id
    IF(tableY.user_id IS NULL, tableX.field2, tableY.other_field2) AS field2,
    etc
FROM (SELECT 1 AS dummy) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableY ON tableY.user_id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableX ON tableX.id = 1
```

Comment: ok thanks this is giving me new idea's this might just do the trick indeed.

Comment: it now says "Missing opening parenthesis" at my first if. So i tried using IFNULL, I edited my post above to see what it does, but gives an error as well... see post @Kickstart

Comment: You do not want to use IFNULL as you are going to check the same column each time (which being the key can't really be NULL). Otherwise you will get a confused value when a column on one table does contain NULL. In your SQL you need to give the sub query an alias name, and it also only wants to return a single row (ie, in mine it is just return a single row with one column containing the value 1).